# Переместить файл в корзину — Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, файлы, файловая-система

Как безопасно удалить файл, то есть переместить его в корзину (Recycle bin), чтобы пользователь самостоятельно смог восстановить его?

- `os.remove` стирает игнорируя корзину
- `os.rmdir` стирает именно директории

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pip3 install send2trash`

```
from send2trash import send2trash
send2trash("directory")
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628517/how-can-i-move-file-into-recycle-bin-trash-on-different-platforms-using-pyqt4)